# Keyword Not Supported: Provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I realize there's similarly titled posts here, I've searched through all of them without finding my solution.

I'm uploading an Excel file to SQL Server in ASP.net MVC. Here's my connection string:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication12-20180107114522.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication12-20180107114522;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And here's my Excel file connection string:

```
string constr = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";", filepath);
```

The rest of my code uses SqlConnection / SqlCommand etc, rather than oleDB commands.

Comment: You're trying to use `SqlConnection` to connect to an Jet database?  Why?

Comment: can you share your code and explain, what problem you are facing at which step?

Comment: @Amy Thank you; changing it to ACE fixed everything.

Comment: @gattoun oh.  well that was unexpectedly easy.  submitted as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `SqlConnection` to connect to SQL Server databases.  That connection type doesn't understand "Provider" in the connection string.

You need to use the appropriate connection type for Jet databases, e.g. `OleDbConnection`.